# what's preventing additions to the current set of R reserved words/symbols?

Tags: r

*Is there a historical precedent of internal changes to the `R` parser, adding new [reserved words](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Reserved-words) or symbols?*

If I remember correctly `data.table` uses a serendipitous `:=` that was once defined but left unused in `R` internals, but I'm not aware of others. However, as the language evolves, it would sometimes seem useful to define new symbols.

An obvious case could be made for magrittr's pipe `%>%` which has become ubiquitous for many, but remains a pain to type (sure, there are keyboard tricks, but still). Similarly, `dplyr/rlang` introduce/repurpose notations for "tidy evaluation" (`!!`, `!!!`, `:=`, `~`, etc.).

Another case I'm seeing is the verbosity of lambda functions. Would it be possible, theoretically, to define internally something like `f = λ(x) x+1` instead of `f = function(x) x+1`, or are there character restrictions on top of other reasons?

Comment: The gsubfn package allows you to preface any function call with `fn$` in which case formula arguments are converted to functions making it easy to specify lambdas.  For example,    `library(gsubfn); fn$aggregate(CO2[,4:5], CO2[, 1:2], ~ mean(range(x)))`.  It assumes the free RHS variables (in the example `x`) are the arguments in the order encountered or you can specify them as a sum on the LHS.

Comment: I don't think there is anything strictly prohibiting the addition of a reserved word like `λ`, but AFAIK doing so would generally require modifying and recompiling R since the parser (which is just a C function) would need to be aware the new symbol(s) and know how to handle them. As noted, data.table takes advantage of the `:=` symbol, but this is only possible because the parser is aware of it -- e.g. see [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/gram.y#L306) and [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/main/gram.c#L898).

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that `formula`s (especially in the `purrr::map` context) in combination with NSE are essentially lambda functions?

Comment: I don't know about R specifically, but language designers in general try very hard _not_ to add new reserved words or symbols unless they have no choice, or unless they are in some sort of pre-reserved namespace, because they don't want to break existing code. For instance, C99 added a keyword `_Bool` (which is in a reserved namespace) but to get the more pleasant name `bool` you have to ask for it explicitly (`#include <stdbool.h>`).

Answer (score 2):

Why add an ergonomics feature if you risk breaking a runtime that hosts a huge ecosystem? Also, once you add one feature, you are on a slippery slope and are staring straight in the face of feature bloat.

And if you say that we can be smart and judicious about what features we add, how do we structure that decision process? R does not have a "benevolent dictator" having a final word in decisions like this so you are left with *design by committee* with all that it entails.

The big thing with R has always been the package ecosystem, in which if you want a feature you write it yourself -- as in your `magrittr` example. The language itself has remained close to its S roots and has successfully served as a stable platform for all the development that has been happening.

Comment: whether you like it or not i) languages do evolve, and R has been no exception, ii) some changes are worth considering, iii) R Core does in fact occasionally consider including "third-party" code into base R and is open to this sort of discussion (cf recent thread on R-devel re unary infix operators), iv) carefully-considered additions are not a slippery slope to feature bloat. I would continue but the tone of your answer is not very inviting.

Comment: Sorry you don't like my tone -- I am just playing devil's advocate here. In fact, I'd like to see some quality-of-life changes to R as well. This being said, tuning the engine of a running car is a complicated and fraught issue and I was trying to convey that in my answer.